# make vim-R-plugin run to get result directly

Tags: r, vim

I have installed vim-R-plugin in my gvim successfully.
When i edit three lines of code .

```
birthday<-function(k){
return(1-prod(c((365-k+1):365))/(365**k))}
birthday(20)
```

What i want to do is get the value of birthday(20) in vim and vim-R-plugin ,i do it this way .

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In a summary,my steps are  :
1.open R console
2.send the code file to R console
There is a still problem , when i send the code in vim to R console, can't get the result of birthday(20) instantly,there is a function of birthday in R console,but the last line **birthday(20)** is not be executed ,i have let it be executed by the two ways.

method 1: to input **birthday(20)** in R console to get it.
method 2:to send the line which contain **birthday(20)** to get it.

what confused me is that i have send three lines as a file to R console,and still resend the last line to R console, the last line was sent for two times ,how can i get the answer not to send the last line **birthday(20)** for two times?

Comment: With regards to free IDEs for R I would suggest RStudio (http://www.rstudio.com/)

Comment: You could also use the entry `File (echo)` (or press `\ae`) to source the file. That should print all code and its output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug-in is doing what you asked for: source your file. Since you do not tell R to print the result, it does not print it. What you "get" by sending the line, I suppose, is an output from interactive session. A key distinction.

Anyway. To answer your question, change the 3rd line of your source from

```
birthday(20)
```

to

```
print(birthday(20))
```

..and source the file. You will have the answer displayed.